# Incorrect syntax in update query: Unable to find one

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ms-access, sql-update

I am getting a weird error in one of my SQL query in my ASP.NET application. I am trying to update an **MS Access** Table row, and the following is my code:

```
try
{
strQry = @"Update UserMaster set Password=@Pwd, RoleID=@RoleID where UserID=@UserID";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pwd", strUserPwd);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleID", intRoleID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", intUserID);
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = strQry;
con.Open();
intReturn = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
```

According to me, what I am able to see is that there are no issues with the update query, as I have been using this kind of method from quite long time but, this is really weird that I am getting a `Syntax error in UPDATE statement` exception.

Can any one help me out

Comment: I know that the way I have passed the update parameters are suited for MS Sql but, it works fine with MS Access as well, untill you have kept the parameter order correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `password` is the reserved word and you need to enclose that in a bracket `[]`
So your query will become

```
strQry = @"Update UserMaster set [Password]=@Pwd, RoleID=@RoleID where UserID=@UserID";
```

Rest all if correct :)

Refer [list of reserve keywords in MS Access 2007 Database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx)

**TIP**: It is always advicable to use `non-reserved` key words, even if you do so then always include `[ ]` to be on safer side. As in hurry you do not realize which reserve key word you mess up wit

Comment: Thanks friend, it really did not strike in my head, though I knew this. You were were really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're using `OleDb` to connect to MsAccess.

Try to change your parameter declaration from `@parameter` to `?` like this.

More : [OleDbParameter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter)

```
try
{
  strQry = @"Update UserMaster set Password=?, RoleID=? where UserID=?";
  var p1 = command.CreateParameter();
  p1.Value = strUserPwd;
  command.Parameters.Add(p1);

  var p2 = command.CreateParameter();
  p2.Value = intRoleID;
  command.Parameters.Add(p2);

  var p3 = command.CreateParameter();
  p3.Value = intUserID;
  command.Parameters.Add(p3);

  cmd.Connection = con;
  cmd.CommandText = strQry;
  con.Open();
  intReturn = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  con.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Probably because the answer you gave was wrong.  The correct answer is that `password` is a reserved word.